# Override thrown exception with a new custom expection

Tags: c#, rest, exception

I am trying to override a exception thrown from my service call, to my own custom exception. I have two custom exceptions I want to use, depending on the StatusCode returned from the service call. Either a ServerException for 500+ or a ClientException for 400+ errors.

```
catch (ApiException e)
{
    if ((int)e.StatusCode >= 400 && (int)e.StatusCode < 500)
    {
        throw new ClientException(e.StatusCode.ToString(), e.Message, e.Uri.ToString(), e.HttpMethod, e.Content, e.StatusCode, e.InnerException.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ServerException(e.StatusCode.ToString(), e.Message, e.Uri.ToString(), e.HttpMethod, e.Content, e.StatusCode, e.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

I need to override the ApiException caught in the example. For some reason the example returns a Exception object with a ApiException as the inner exception. Doesn't return the Client or Server Exception.

The call to the service:

```
catch(ClientException e)
 {}
catch(ServerException e)
 {}
catch (ApiException e)
 {}
catch (Exception e)
 {
  //Always caught here only
 }
```

ClientException class, shortened for readability:

```
public class ClientException : Exception
{
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public string ReasonPhrase { get; private set; }
    public ClientException(string code, string message) : base(message)
    {
        Code = code;
        ReasonPhrase = message;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Isn't the enclosing method asynchronous? (i.e. Task-based)

Comment: Using refit for service call, so the service call itself is async, but not the method which holds the call.

Comment: Are you sure that you're actually catching the exception?

Comment: Yes 100% sure, I have a breakpoint that breaks on the throw new ..

Comment: Would you mind showing the ClientException class? I'm assuming it's derived from Exception and probably a method implementation issue.

Comment: @cfl can you show method definition? is it async?

Comment: did you call base constructor of Exception class in custom exception class ?

Comment: What is the exact type of exception being "returned" here? Is it just `System.Exception` or some other type? Have you checked any interim layers of code, do they have try/catch blocks of their own that may be the culprit?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes its System.Exception. There is one more layer between, but its just a call to service nothing else - no try catch there

Comment: @A.T. If I understand exactly what you mean then yes. Its created new with throw new ServerException(...)

Comment: Are you sure that the type of exceptions you are throwing and catching are same? I mean they belong to the same library? The exception definition you shared does not have constructor accepting more than two arguments.

Comment: A wild guess, it could happen that the `new ClientException` and `new ServerException` lines themselves are throwing exception which are not of any of the types you are catching. Can you just initialize and throw `ClientException` and `ServerException` with dummy status and message and see if they are being caught properly? That way you will be sure that their initialization is cause of other exception or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  your  code throw an ApiException like

```
public void  foo(){
....
throe new ApiException();
}
```

and in your code you have

```
try
{
    foo();//throe ApiException
}
catch(ClientException e)
 {}
catch(ServerException e)
 {}
catch (ApiException e)
 {
     var ex=ExceptionLocator.Get(ExceptionCode);//use ExceptionLocator  to locate your custom exception  
     throw ex;
 }
catch (Exception e)
 {
  //Always caught here only
 }

public abstract class BusinessException : Exception
{
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public string ReasonPhrase { get; private set; }
    public ClientException(string code, string message) : base(message)
    {
        Code = code;
        ReasonPhrase = message;
    }
 }

public class ClientException:BusinessException
{

}

public class ServerException:BusinessException
{

}

public static class ExceptionLocator{
    static Dictionary<int,BusinessException> locator=new Dictionary<int,BusinessException>();

    public ExceptionLocator()
    {
        locator.Add(400,new ClientException());
        locator.Add(500,new ServerException());
        ....
    }
    public static BusinessException Get(int code)
    {
        return locator[code];
    }
}
```

you can use an ExceptionLocator to locate your custom exception Or in Foo() decide  throw ClientException Or ServerException

Comment: what library did you use for ExceptionLocator? thanks

Comment: @cfl I Update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have no method defined that accepts your parameters

```
throw new ClientException(
    e.StatusCode.ToString(),
    e.Message, 
    e.Uri.ToString(), 
    e.HttpMethod, 
    e.Content, 
    e.StatusCode, 
    e.InnerException.Message);
```

You need a method in the class such as

```
public ClientException(
    string StatusCode,
    string Message, 
    string Uri 
    string HttpMethod, 
    string Content, 
    string StatusCode, 
    string InnerExceptionMessage) : base(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
public ClientException(params object[] args)
        : base(...) { }
```